# Cannot resolve DNS -> Refresh -> Loading

Tags: domain-name-system

Hi I'm not the actual Network guy here, but he is off for a long time with Health issues.

We're running 150 employees in this place, and the past few months we're been having slight issues I'm hoping someone can help trouble shoot.

Here is the thing, when people use the internet.. in 1 out of 50 pages loading

a website will simply not load(external pages).. as if the DNS doesn't resolve..
it just goes straight to 'cannot display website'
you hit the refresh button and straight away it loads the page.

Now the internet is not down at any point during this.
We're running a DNS server, we're in the middle of migrating to Windows 2012 from 2008, and going in the cloud with Windows Azure.

I was hoping someone could just point me in the right direction...
cause I really dont know where to start.. the DNS server does not report any errors, and seem to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

There might be a plethora of issues here. Some things to try out:

- Determine exactly which stations display this problem. Hence you will know if this behaviour affects a set of machines, or all of them. That way you will be able to start pinpointing if this is a server side issue or not.
- Bearing in mind the above, the issue might be related to failing/faulty LAN. If this is ca. 150 machines, you probably have many switches. Two very useful things are an adaptive ping and a flood ping. `ping -A`, and `ping -i`. Both available under Linux.
- Also check the stats for ports on the switches (I assume they are managed). Look for things like runts and underruns. Remember though that collisions are a normal thing.
- If, however, the problem seems to be affecting all stations, and you rule out LAN problems this might be something to do with the router.
- Also - how do you assert that this is due to DNS not responding?